# Elements not staying within there container - specifically chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JSFIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/adtdjog2/
Note: I am very inexperienced in programming as you can tell by the simplistic website here.

I am trying to figure out why everything is flowing outside the container div, with the exception of the search function?

BTW I have been using Chrome to view and test all programming. I noticed that it looks different when I put it in the jsfiddle, so not sure what I am doing wrong here in terms of sizing and positioning all elements.

Below is the code

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>      
<body>  
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 logo"><img src="img/logo.PNG"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <div class="col-md-2 menu">Dashboard</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 menu">Invoicing</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 menu">Scheduler</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 menu">Employees</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 menu">User Management</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 menu">Customers</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <div class="col-md-2 button">New Employee</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 button">Employee Schedule</div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:right">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Employees..." required class="searchbox">
                    <input type="button" value="Search" class="searchbutton">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="resultbox row"> 
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="col-md-2 table_cell">Name</div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 table_cell">Status</div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 table_cell">Phone</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 table_cell">Email</div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 table_cell">Title</div>
                    <br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    margin:auto auto; 
    width:975px;
}


.resultbox
{
    width:975px;
    height: 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(212, 0, 0, 0), #795548);
    /*line-height: 50px;*/
    text-align:left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #666;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.logo
{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.menu 
{
    width: 162px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(gray, #eee);
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #666;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;


}

.button
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(212, 0, 0, 0), #795548);
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    /*border-radius: 5px;*/
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #666;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;

}

.table
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.table_cell
{
    display:table-cell;
    width:194px;
    border: solid black 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.searchbox
{
    height: 45px;
    width: 200px;

}
.searchbutton
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

[Please see image for overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrh1e.png)

Comment: works well! what do you see? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I don't see anything flowing out of the container div.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced and it is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You have two primary issues:

1) You're using fixed width elements that don't account for any change in viewport (ie **They are not responsive**) See [Media Queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

2) You're not really using the grid system properly; for instance this > `<div class="row col-md-12">` makes no sense. See [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

I know this is new to you so learning the fundamental principles of HTML/CSS (at the very least) is essential so you understand how Bootstrap works in general along with digging into the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/).

See working example Snippet below of how you could structure your code.

```css
/**For Nav Pills Navigation**/

/*#nav {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}*/

div.logo {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.navbar#nav-menu {
  background: linear-gradient(gray, #eee);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar #menu > li {
  background: linear-gradient(gray, #eee);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#searchForm .btn.btn-navi {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(212, 0, 0, 0), #795548);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
}
div.resultbox {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(212, 0, 0, 0), #795548);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/**For NAVBAR Navigation**/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar#nav-menu {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  div.resultbox {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1150x300/f00/fff" class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Can be repalced with the below NAV PILLS -->
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="nav-menu">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Invoicing</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Scheduler</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Employees</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">User Management</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Customers</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<!--Can be used Instead of the above NAVBAR -->
<!--<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="nav">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Dashboard</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Invoicing</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Scheduler</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Employees</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">User Management</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Customers</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form id="searchForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block btn-navi">New Employee</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block btn-navi">Employee Schedule</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-navi" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="resultbox">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Title</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vanburen - Thank-you so much for your help. I am envious of your talent. I am working through the code you supplied to help understand and learn why your code has a much more impressive output. My first question is that I noticed you used multiple containers, is there a particular reason a developer would divide the page with multiple containers as you laid out?

Comment: In this particular example you could enclose everything in one container and it would not change anything structure wise. I think for an example it helps a great deal to see the clear divide in the page structure and as far whether or not to use separate containers (or whatever it may be) it ultimately depends on the particular application. If you can use less code (and avoid duplication) you should (it doesn't always make sense tho as you may want to style, etc different elements inside a container so it may be more practical to use them separately).